# Error when attempting to input strings into dynamically allocated array

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to code the following program to read a single word per line from a text document, then print the same words to another text document, but for some reason I am encountering a rather large error after adding in:

```
for(int i = 0; i < num_lines; i++)
{
    getline (myfile_in, line);
    stringstream(line) >> arr[i];
}
```

Im not sure why this is causing an error because I copied this loop from a program that I wrote previously. The error goes away once i remove the stringstream line, but as far as I'm aware, I need it in order to copy the contents over to the array. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{   
ifstream myfile_in;
myfile_in.open ("words_in.txt");
ofstream myfile_out;
myfile_out.open ("words_out.txt");

string line;
int num_lines = 0;
string *arr;

assert (!myfile_in.fail());
myfile_in >> line;

while (!myfile_in.eof())
{
    getline (myfile_in, line);
    num_lines++;
}

arr = new string[num_lines];

for(int i = 0; i < num_lines; i++)
{
    getline (myfile_in, line);
    stringstream(line) >> arr[i];
}

for(int i = 0; i < num_lines; i++)
{
    myfile_out << arr[i] << endl;
}

myfile_in.close();
myfile_out.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while (!myfile_in.eof())` I believe you will read past the end of the file this way

Comment: Hmm, how would I fix this?

Comment: Why aren't you using `arr[i] = line` or `arr[i] = string(line)` ?

Comment: @malhotraprateek shouldn't `stringstream(line) >> arr[i]` accomplish a similar thing?

Comment: Dont know :P never used that but it seems a tad complicated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not `getline (myfile_in, arr[i]);` ?

Comment: I just tried that, it doesn't crash when compiling, but it just prints blank lines in the output file.

Comment: @CalebMoriarty That's because in `while (!myfile_in.eof())` loop you had read all lines in the file. If you need to read them again, you can try reopening the file.

Comment: @CalebMoriarty And I believe using a `std::vector` may be a better solution in your problem.

Comment: Im sure it would be, but I haven't learned about that in class yet haha.

Comment: @CalebMoriarty lol. The solution is simple, add `myfile_in.seekg(0)` right after the while loop.

Comment: Do you mind explaining what that does? I want to know how everything is working instead of just making it work for the grade haha.

Comment: @CalebMoriarty These two lines points `myfile_in` at the beginning of your input file so that you can read from it again :)

Comment: thank you! That worked! I thought it might have been something like that but I wasn't entirely sure.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, after while loop you've already read whole file. And then in for loop you again trying to readline from this stream. I think, you should remove readline command from for loop.